# how to play random sound without repeat ?after playing all file then again start new cycle of sound

Tags: javascript, ios

I want to play sound in randomly without repeating at once time.All sound played after again start new cycle of random sound.

For Example:we have 5 file.

start random playing:3,1,5,2,4(this is right)--- 3,1,3,5,2,4(this is wrong)

Comment: Are you struggling with how to code it or the concept? If it is the concept I can post some pseudocode to show you how the logic would work if you are stuck with a specific code problem please post your current code.

Comment: One way you could play your sounds in a (pseudo) random, non-repeating order is to store the file names in an array, shuffle it using [one of the methods provided here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), then iterate through the array and play each of the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually this is how I would approach this problem

- Store all your sounds into an array
- randomize your array
- Store that array into a nsuserdefaults. So that in case user closes and relaunches app then you still have that randomized array
- count how many sounds have been played. Store the count into a nsuserdefaults as well. (for same reason as above)
- Now once the count reaches array count then randomize the array again and start all over.

Kinda makes sense?